# json table in powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I am learning some powershell with JSON and i have problem with get some value. I have file:

```
{
"expand":  "renderedFields,names,schema,operations,editmeta,changelog,versionedRepresentations",
"id":  "2966576",
"self":  "https://hostname/rest/api/2/issue/2966576",
"key":  "My_Key-369",
"fields":  {
               "subtasks":  [
                                "@{id=2966577; key=My_Key-370; self=https://hostname/rest/api/2/issue/2966577; fields=}",
                                "@{id=2966578; key=My_Key-371; self=https://hostname/rest/api/2/issue/2966578; fields=}",
                                "@{id=2966579; key=My_Key-372; self=https://hostname/rest/api/2/issue/2966579; fields=}",
                                "@{id=2966580; key=My_Key-373; self=https://hostname/rest/api/2/issue/2966580; fields=}",
                                "@{id=2966581; key=My_Key-374; self=https://hostname/rest/api/2/issue/2966581; fields=}",
                                "@{id=2966582; key=My_Key-375; self=https://hostname/rest/api/2/issue/2966582; fields=}",
                                "@{id=2966583; key=My_Key-376; self=https://hostname/rest/api/2/issue/2966583; fields=}",
                                "@{id=2966584; key=My_Key-377; self=https://hostname/rest/api/2/issue/2966584; fields=}",
                                "@{id=2966585; key=My_Key-378; self=https://hostname/rest/api/2/issue/2966585; fields=}",
                                "@{id=2966586; key=My_Key-379; self=https://hostname/rest/api/2/issue/2966586; fields=}",
                                "@{id=2966587; key=My_Key-380; self=https://hostname/rest/api/2/issue/2966587; fields=}",
                                "@{id=2966588; key=My_Key-381; self=https://hostname/rest/api/2/issue/2966588; fields=}",
                                "@{id=2966589; key=My_Key-382; self=https://hostname/rest/api/2/issue/2966589; fields=}",
                                "@{id=2966590; key=My_Key-383; self=https://hostname/rest/api/2/issue/2966590; fields=}"
                            ]
           }
```

}

I want have My_Key-*** in separate variables. I cant access to this subtasks table. Could you help me how can get this value?

Comment: What have you tried so far and what were the results?  [ConvertFrom-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7.2) would be a good place to start.

Comment: As an aside, your ```subtasks``` entries look like they've been serialised incorrectly - they appear to contain a string representation of a PowerShell hashtable rather than a nested json object. This might result in data loss and difficulty deserialising the string, so you may need to review how you're generating the json file in the first place...

Comment: See also @mklement0’s answer here for pretty much the same issue in another question… https://stackoverflow.com/a/73242200/3156906