# Powershell Access Nested Object in JSON after using ConvertFrom-Json

Tags: json, powershell, convertfrom-json

I've been able to parse some JSON succesfully up to a point but cannot access a specific object:

My overall code:

```
$myFile = Get-Content -Raw -Path UKStore.json | ConvertFrom-Json

$counter = 0
foreach ($link in $myFile.links)
{
    Write-Host $link.id "and" $link.name
    Write-Host $link.default_sku
    $counter+=1

}

Write-Host $counter
Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

Now, what I get for each iteration is something like this below. So, line 1 is great and is outputting what I need but line 2 needs to be processed further:

```
EP9000-NPEE00001_00-GCRASHBAND000001 and Crash Bandicoot®

@{amortizeFlag=False; bundleExclusiveFlag=False; chargeImmediatelyFlag=False; charge_type_id=0; credit_card_required_flag=0; defaultSku=True; display_price=£3.99; eligibilities=System.Object[]; entitlements=System.Object[]; id=EP9000-NPEE00001_00-GCRASHBAND000001-EE03; is_original=False; name=Full Game; platforms=System.Object[]; price=399; rewards=System.Object[]; seasonPassExclusiveFlag=False; skuAvailabilityOverrideFlag=False; sku_type=0; type=standard}
```

I simply cannot, no matter what notation I try get access to the properties in "$link.default_sku" I'm clearly not connecting something right in my brain but I feel that:

```
$link.default_sku.display_price
```

Should give me the value £3.99 from the above object but instead I get nothing returned at all. Any help to get through this mental blockage would be great.

Went a level higher for Format-Custom

```
$link | Format-Custom
```

Output:

```
class PSCustomObject
    {
      bucket = games
      container_type = product
      content_type = 1
      default_sku = @{amortizeFlag=False; bundleExclusiveFlag=False; chargeImmediatelyFlag=False; charge_type_id=0;
      credit_card_required_flag=0; defaultSku=True; display_price=£24.99; eligibilities=System.Object[];
      entitlements=System.Object[]; id=EP2595-CUSA07370_00-0001000100010001-E001; is_original=False; name=Full Game;
      platforms=System.Object[]; price=2499; rewards=System.Object[]; seasonPassExclusiveFlag=False;
      skuAvailabilityOverrideFlag=False; sku_type=0; type=standard}
      gameContentTypesList =
      game_contentType = Full Game
      id = EP2595-CUSA07370_00-0001000100010001
      images =
      name = Past Cure™
      playable_platform = PS4™
      provider_name = Phantom 8 Studio UG
      release_date =
        class DateTime
        {
          Date =
            class DateTime
            {
              Date =
                class DateTime
                {
                  Date =
                    class DateTime
                    {
                      Date =
                        class DateTime
                        {
                          Date = 23/02/2018 00:00:00
                          Day = 23
                          DayOfWeek = Friday
                          DayOfYear = 54
                          Hour = 0
                          Kind = Utc
                          Millisecond = 0
                          Minute = 0
                          Month = 2
                          Second = 0
                          Ticks = 636549408000000000
                          TimeOfDay = 00:00:00
                          Year = 2018
                          DateTime = 23 February 2018 00:00:00
                        }
                      Day = 23
                      DayOfWeek = Friday
                      DayOfYear = 54
                      Hour = 0
                      Kind = Utc
                      Millisecond = 0
                      Minute = 0
                      Month = 2
                      Second = 0
                      Ticks = 636549408000000000
                      TimeOfDay =
                        class TimeSpan
                        {
                          Ticks = 0
                          Days = 0
                          Hours = 0
                          Milliseconds = 0
                          Minutes = 0
                          Seconds = 0
                          TotalDays = 0
                          TotalHours = 0
                          TotalMilliseconds = 0
                          TotalMinutes = 0
                          TotalSeconds = 0
                        }
                      Year = 2018
                      DateTime = 23 February 2018 00:00:00
                    }
                  Day = 23
                  DayOfWeek = Friday
                  DayOfYear = 54
                  Hour = 0
                  Kind = Utc
                  Millisecond = 0
                  Minute = 0
                  Month = 2
                  Second = 0
                  Ticks = 636549408000000000
                  TimeOfDay =
                    class TimeSpan
                    {
                      Ticks = 0
                      Days = 0
                      Hours = 0
                      Milliseconds = 0
                      Minutes = 0
                      Seconds = 0
                      TotalDays = 0
                      TotalHours = 0
                      TotalMilliseconds = 0
                      TotalMinutes = 0
                      TotalSeconds = 0
                    }
                  Year = 2018
                  DateTime = 23 February 2018 00:00:00
                }
              Day = 23
              DayOfWeek = Friday
              DayOfYear = 54
              Hour = 0
              Kind = Utc
              Millisecond = 0
              Minute = 0
              Month = 2
              Second = 0
              Ticks = 636549408000000000
              TimeOfDay =
                class TimeSpan
                {
                  Ticks = 0
                  Days = 0
                  Hours = 0
                  Milliseconds = 0
                  Minutes = 0
                  Seconds = 0
                  TotalDays = 0
                  TotalHours = 0
                  TotalMilliseconds = 0
                  TotalMinutes = 0
                  TotalSeconds = 0
                }
              Year = 2018
              DateTime = 23 February 2018 00:00:00
            }
          Day = 23
          DayOfWeek = Friday
          DayOfYear = 54
          Hour = 0
          Kind = Utc
          Millisecond = 0
          Minute = 0
          Month = 2
          Second = 0
          Ticks = 636549408000000000
          TimeOfDay =
            class TimeSpan
            {
              Ticks = 0
              Days = 0
              Hours = 0
              Milliseconds = 0
              Minutes = 0
              Seconds = 0
              TotalDays = 0
              TotalHours = 0
              TotalMilliseconds = 0
              TotalMinutes = 0
              TotalSeconds = 0
            }
          Year = 2018
          DateTime = 23 February 2018 00:00:00
        }
      restricted = False
      revision = 15
      short_name = Past Cure™
      timestamp = 1648353047000
      top_category = downloadable_game
      url = https://store.playstation.com/store/api/chihiro/00_09_000/container/GB/en/999/EP2595-CUSA07370_00-0001000100010
      001/1648353047
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`$link.default_sku` contains a *string*,** not a nested object, and that's why `$link.default_sku.display_price` doesn't work.

That **string happens to be the *stringification* of a nested `[pscsutomobject]`**, such as you would get with string interpolation (e.g., `"$([pscustomobject] @{ foo=1; bar =2 })"` or - most likely in this case - when the default recursion depth of 2 is exceeded during *creation* of JSON text using [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json), a common and regrettable pitfall - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53583677/45375).

You have two options:

- **Fix the problem at the source**, by passing a `-Depth` argument that is sufficiently high to `ConvertTo-Json` to prevent truncation when the `UKStore.json` file is created.
- If that is not an option, you'll have to **do *text parsing*** to extract the value of interest from the string. Note, however, that this isn't generally *robust*, because the stringification format of `[pscustomobject]`s is meant for the human observer, not for *programmatic* processing. Notably, quotation marks around string values with spaces are lost:

  ```
  # -> '£24.99'
  $link.default_sku -replace '(?s).+\bdisplay_price=([^;]+).+', '$1'
  ```

Comment: This was it - increasing Depth to 5 for the initial creation of UKStore.json let me access the display_price. Thanks so much, I just couldn't figure this out!!

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Nealbo; my pleasure. The behavior is far from obvious; in recent versions of PowerShell (Core) you at least get a _warning_.